# Is the colimit of a filtered diagram of module categories in AbCat induced by a cofiltered diagram of rings equivalent to the category of modules over the limit?

Tags: abelian-categories

Given a cofiltered diagram of commutative rings $F:D\to \mathrm{CRing}$, we obtain a filtered diagram $\mathrm{Mod}(F):D^{op}\to \mathrm{ExAbCat}$ (where $\mathrm{ExAbCat}$ is the category of Abelian categories with exact additive functors between them) induced by the contravariant functor $CRing^{op}\to \mathrm{ExAbCat}$ sending the maps $f:A\to B$ in $\mathrm{CRing}$ to the restriction functor, $f^*:B\mathrm{-Mod}\to A\mathrm{-Mod}$.

Then here's the question: 
Is $\varinjlim \mathrm{Mod}(F)$ equivalent to $(\varprojlim F)\mathrm{-Mod}$?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Do you really mean to ask whether *limits* in the category of commutative rings are taken to *colimits* in the (2-)category of abelian categories? Or did you actually mean to ask whether (filtered) colimits in commutative rings are taken to limits in the category of abelian categories? I believe the answer is "no" for the first and "yes" for the second (under reasonable interpretations, which depend on the exact interpretation of the category or 2-category of abelian categories), and I think I'm prepared to say more, but I need to ask first whether you're sure this is what you meant to ask. 

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! 
I actually meant the first. If it was not entirely clear what I meant, it is probably because I am still a bit confused :-) 
So, the answer is "no" I guess. Is there an easy way to see that? 


Comment: Oh, and if there are still details you need to know, which I was unable to express, let me know, I will try take make myself clearer.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I am severely mistaken, the answer to the question as stated is "no". (There is by the way some slight disagreement in the literature as to what "filtered category" means; for many, a filtered poset means a nonempty poset where any two elements have an upper bound, but in Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, Mac Lane and Moerdijk mean that any two elements have a lower bound. I don't think this affects my answer.)

Let us take for instance the ring of $p$-adic integers as inverse limit of the (directed in either sense) system

$$\ldots \to \mathbb{Z}/(p^{n+1}) \to \mathbb{Z}/(p^n) \to \ldots$$

Each of these commutative rings $A$ can be viewed as an $Ab$-enriched category, and the abelian category of left modules over $A$ can be viewed as the $Ab$-enriched category of $Ab$-enriched functors $A \to Ab$. So we are homming into $Ab$, and the usual expectation is that a contravariant hom-functor takes colimits to limits (I will tighten up this statement in a moment), but not limits to colimits; the question as stated has to do with the latter situation.

The filtered colimit (and it would be reasonable to interpret "colimit" in a 2-categorical sense) of the system of full subcategory inclusions

$$\ldots \to Ab^{\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)} \to Ab^{\mathbb{Z}/(p^{n+1})} \to \ldots$$

can be taken to be the union of these (abelian) categories. The union is just the category of those abelian groups where each object is completely annihilated by some $p^n$ (not uniformly of course; the $n$ depends on the group); in particular, they are all torsion. On the other hand, most objects in the category of modules over the $p$-adic integers, for example the $p$-adic integers itself, are not torsion. So there's your counterexample.

But if we turn the directions around, then indeed (filtered) colimits are taken to limits. There are some slightly tricky issues to deal with; first, "morally", we really ought to be working with 2-categorical limits -- weak limits to be precise. To do it right, we should be working with the category of commutative rings as a 2-category (construing ring homomorphisms as enriched functors and taking 2-cells as natural transformations), but if I'm not mistaken, weak colimits in this 2-category of commutative rings coincide with ordinary colimits of commutative rings, and we can relax. Second, there is the issue of whether colimits of diagrams of commutative rings are identified with the corresponding colimit qua $Ab$-enriched categories -- in fact this is not true in full generality (e.g., the coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$ in commutative rings is the terminal ring, whereas the coproduct in $Ab$-enriched categories is gotten by taking a disjoint sum). However, considering the inclusions

$$\text{CRing} \hookrightarrow \text{Ring} \hookrightarrow \text{AbCat}$$

one finds that both preserve *filtered* colimits (for the second inclusion, we're saying one-object $Ab$-enriched categories are closed under filtered colimits), so we make that restriction.

With those caveats squared away, a general fact is that homming into an object like $Ab$, giving here a functor

$$Ab^{-}: \text{CRing}^{op} \to \text{AbCat},$$

takes (weak) filtered colimits to (weak) limits.

Comment: @Todd: I think you mean "strong limit" "homotopy limit" or "pseudo-limit", not "weak limit", which I'm sure you're aware means something completely different =).

Comment: @Harry: "weak limit" is also used (I am aware of your other sense, where a unique existence condition is changed to an existence condition). Funnily enough, it means "strong limit". :-) 

Comment: Yup, that's the one!

Comment: Anyway, I think that it's actually strictly true by merit of the fact that the Mod(-) functor is a left-adjoint.  Specifically, it's left-adjoint to the functor sending an abelian category to the ring of endomorphisms of the identity functor.  

Comment: Harry, that doesn't seem right to me. If for example $A = Ab$, then you are saying that exact additive functors $Mod(R) \to Ab$ are somehow equivalent to ring homomorphisms $R \to \mathbb{Z}$? 

Comment: There's contravariance involved.

Comment: Let me ask again: are you suggesting that exact additive functors $Mod(R) \to Ab$ are somehow equivalent to ring homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to R$? Please clarify, and I'll have a look later.

Comment: I think I'm suggesting that $CRing^{op}$ is a (co?)reflective subcategory of $AbCat$, but I was trying to work it out, and I wasn't sure exactly what you want the morphisms in AbCat to be.  I think you might want them to be something like "additive functors with left-adjoints". I remember reading about something like this in relation to noncommutative algebraic geometry.  The idea, at least, is that the ring of endomorphisms of the identity functor is the "center" commutative ring attached to an abelian category.  It's well known that if R is comm, the end. ring of the id. on R-mod is iso to R

Comment: I think you'd better let this one cook a little longer, Harry. Remember that left adjoints between module categories correspond to bimodules. Even if you were to talk about functors which are simultaneously left and right adjoints, these correspond not to ring homomorphisms but rather to adjoint bimodule pairs, and there tend to be many of those even when there are few ring homomorphisms. For example, if $k$ is a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then any finite-dimensional $k$-space and its dual give such an adjoint pair. 

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  I guess there's no good way to get back to CRing from AbCat.  I wonder if you can classify exactly which functors $Mod-R\to Mod-S$ exactly classify homomorphisms in a non-useless way.

Comment: Probably this is not what Todd meant, but his post sounds a bit like taking module categories generally takes colimits of commutative rings to limits of module categories. This is clearly not true though (take the coproduct of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$). The problem is that in general colimits of commutative rings don't go to colimits of abelian-group enriched categories. But this is true for filtered colimits, I suppose.

Comment: @LennartMeier You're right; thanks. I'll fix this later when I have more leisure to do so.